# How to return PDF file from controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to return a PDF file from a Controller Endpoint using NestJs. When not setting the `Content-type` header, the data returned by `getDocumentFile`  gets returned to the user just fine. When I add the header however, the return I get seems to be some strange form of a GUID, the response always looks like this: `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where `x` is a lowercase hexadecimal character. It also seems to be totally unrelated to the actual return value of the handler function, as I even get this strange GUID-thing when not returning anything at all.

When not setting `Content-type: application/pdf`, the function returns the data of the buffer just fine, however I need to set the header in order to get the browser to recognize the response as a PDF file which is important for my use case.

The controller looks like this:

```
@Controller('documents')
export class DocumentsController {
  constructor(private documentsService: DocumentsService) {}

  @Get(':id/file')
  @Header('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
  async getDocumentFile(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    const document = await this.documentsService.byId(id)
    const pdf = await this.documentsService.getFile(document)

    // using ReadableStreamBuffer as suggested by contributor
    const stream = new ReadableStreamBuffer({
      frequency: 10,
      chunkSize: 2048,
    })
    stream.put(pdf)
    return stream
  }
}
```

and my DocumentsService like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentsService {
  async getAll(): Promise<Array<DocumentDocument>> {
    return DocumentModel.find({})
  }

  async byId(id: string): Promise<DocumentDocument> {
    return DocumentModel.findOne({ _id: id })
  }

  async getFile(document: DocumentDocument): Promise<Buffer> {
    const filename = document.filename
    const filepath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', '..', '..', 'pdf-generator', 'dist', filename)

    const pdf = await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(filepath, {}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(data)
      })
    })
    return pdf
  }
}
```

I originally just returned the buffer (`return pdf`), but that brought the same result as the attempt above. On the repository of NestJs a user suggested to use the above method, which obviously does not work for me either. See the GitHub thread [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1090).

Comment: There is no error, but, as I described above, I don't get the PDF data as a return but a seemingly random GUID (which is different on every request, btw). No error message whatsoever, just not the result I want, obviously

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: not similar but i couldn't manage to download file from a React App using axios. All i'm getting is empty blob data or this output `<Buffer 25 50 44 46  ... >`

Answer (score 18):

Update 2021:

From now on in Nest Version 8 you can use the class `StreamableFile`:

```
import { Controller, Get, StreamableFile } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

@Controller('file')
export class FileController {
  @Get()
  getFile(): StreamableFile {
    const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
    return new StreamableFile(file);
  }
}
```

More info in the offical Nest Docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files

Answer (score 9):

You can just use ready decorator @Res this is my working solution:

Controller(NestJs):

```
async getNewsPdfById(@Param() getNewsParams: GetNewsPdfParams, @Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response): Promise<void> {
  const stream = await this.newsService.getNewsPdfById(getNewsParams.newsId, request.user.ownerId);

  response.set({
    'Content-Type': 'image/pdf',
  });

  stream.pipe(response);
}
```

In my case stream variable is just ready stream created by html-pdf library because i create pdf by html https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf but it doesnt matter how you create your stream. The thing is that you should use @Res decorator and pipe it because its native NestJs solution.

Also here is code how to claim file on client side:
https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Anyway lets try this one in your case:

```
@Controller('documents')
export class DocumentsController {
  constructor(private documentsService: DocumentsService) {}

  @Get(':id/file')
  async getDocumentFile(@Param('id') id: string, @Res res: Response): Promise<Buffer> {
    const document = await this.documentsService.byId(id)
    const pdf = await this.documentsService.getFile(document)


    const stream = new ReadableStreamBuffer({
      frequency: 10,
      chunkSize: 2048,
    })

    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'image/pdf',
    });

    stream.pipe(res);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done.  This covers the easy use of @Res and setting headers in the response, however I needed to use res.headers.set.  Otherwise Beautiful!  Combine this with the next post with the file attachment and it's perfect.

Comment: Here's the missing part.  Response needs to be imported from "express.js" and not "@nestjs/common".  Also, then use res.type() and res.attachment().

Answer (score 8):

It works for me.

```
@Get('pdf')
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@Header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
@Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf')
pdf() {
    return createReadStream('./nodejs.pdf');
}
```

BTW, I think it should be better to use `Stream` instead of `readFile`. Because it loads all contents of the file into RAM.

Comment: I copied your exact code (and replaced the filename, obviously) but the result is still the same... which version of Nest are you using?

Comment: i had to add `.pipe(response)` on the created read stream for it to work (and remove the `Content-Disposition` header)

Comment: Doesn't works for me, I create a pdf using html-pdf like a buffer (even as a stream), with header _content-type application/pdf_ the response is empty, but when I only set _content-disposition_ works fine...

Comment: The problem was Postman, with Insomia or other clients rest finally I can view response and download pdf succes

Answer (score 6):

I know this old thread. But it might help someone.
similar to @Victor

```js
  @Get('pdf')
  @HttpCode(201)
  @Header('Content-Type', 'image/pdf')
  @Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf')
  public pdf() {
    return fs.createReadStream('./test.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: Won't this lead to a download of the file? What I originally wanted was to display the pdf in the browser

Comment: Try to replace the `attachment` into `inline`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 5):

Updated in 2021 too:

I prefer this way as I don't need the post-controller interceptor logic.
We can control the name of the file and make it be inline or downloading the file.

```
@Get()
  download(@Res() res) {
    const filename = '123.pdf';
    // make it to be inline other than downloading
    // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    const filestream = createReadStream('files/' + filename);
    filestream.pipe(res);
  }
```

More info in the offical Nest Docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files

Answer (score 1):

Using the [StreamableFile](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) API:

```
  @Get('openPdf/:filename')
  async openPdf(
    @Param('filename') filename: string,
    @Response({ passthrough: true }) res: Res,
  ):Promise<StreamableFile> {
    try {
     
      //if your pdf or file is other directory add this process.cwd()+'/parentfolder/childfolder' or else leave at it is like below
      const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(join(process.cwd(),`${filename}.pdf` ));
     //set application type as you need json,pdf etc
      res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${filename}.pdf`
      })
        // return readableStream.pipe(res)
      const streamdata= new StreamableFile(readableStream)
      return streamdata
    } catch (error) {
      return error.message
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, "StreamableFile"  can be used to v8 and upper versions. Every time I look at NestJS it doesn't match the needs and version of NestJS. This is a terrible thing...