# Returning a blob with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, backend, blob

I need to send a image as blob via a nestjs api
when i log the blob it comes perfect
[console.log(blob)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du4CL.png)
but when i call it with insomnia it returns a blank object
[Insomnina response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRYPM.png)

I tried calling in the front and converting to a blob again but it seems like it lost data since the size was shrink to 15 from 50k+

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the official NestJs documentation about streaming files [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files). But first, if what you're trying to do is to return a readable stream from a buffer with no file involved, then you need to handle that buffer first as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891242/how-to-pass-a-buffer-as-argument-of-fs-createreadstream). Then you can simply pipe the result using `stream.pipe(res)`.

Comment: The import for StreamableFile doesn't seem to work, i tried updating nestjs but it didnt work, im running the 7.6.15
`Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'StreamableFile'.`

Comment: If you use the nestjs v8 or lower, you might take a look at the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504621/how-to-return-pdf-file-from-controller]. You might want to utilize the createReadStream() function.